# Performing operation on transactional insert

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Using MS SQL Server to replicate data between 2 servers for security purposes. Is it possible to perform an operation on the data sent from the publisher database before it is inserted into the subscriber table?

I have a table (lets call it `DeviceData`) that has a column `DeviceName` on the publisher. `DeviceData` is being subscribed to on the subscriber database, however I need `DeviceData` to have a foreign key on it referencing a table `Device`. Is there anyway to check what data is not in table `Device` in column `DeviceName` and insert it into `Device` before it is inserted into `DeviceData`?

Here is a visual example I drew:
[image]

Comment: you can change the way how changes are propagated with a custom stored procedure that does an insert in your device table and then an insert in your device data table.
take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-articles-specify-how-changes-are-propagated?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MBuschi that comment really does deserve to be an answer

Comment: I was responding from the car.... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to MBuschi's great idea, you can also look into possibly using an [`INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/) on the `DeviceData` table. This trigger would first verify the data you need is in the `Device` table, and then would insert the replicated data into your `DeviceData` table. (Here's Microsoft's [Books Online for Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).)

One pro of this solution is it doesn't muck about in your replication setup (should you ever need to script it and redeploy it). While Microsoft offers docs on how to accomplish MBuschi's solution, in general I find the more customizations to a replication topology, the more of a pain it can turn into to manage in the long term.

But an even better pro of using a trigger is that it decouples the data synchronization feature you use from the relational integrity logic you're trying to support. So if one day you decided to switch from replication to another synchronization technology such as SSIS (or even another type of replication), you wouldn't have to re-implement a solution to account for the `Device` table. Using a trigger ensures that your relational integrity logic is saved at the table level, and is applied no matter where the insert into your `DeviceData` table comes from.

Comment: This sounds like a good method but will SQL Server not remove that trigger once the schema is reset through a snapshot restore?

Comment: @JudasMoses You mean a backup restore?...if the backup was taken before the Trigger was created, then yes the Trigger would be gone, but that's true for *pretty much* any solution you could implement. As long as you take regular backups though, and end up restoring one after when the Trigger was created, then the Trigger will remain.

Comment: No I'm talking about when a subscriber is reinitialised. All replicated tables on the subscriber are dropped and recreated.

Comment: @JudasMoses It depends on the kind of Trigger you create, but yes if it's a Table Trigger and you have replication setup to drop and recreate the tables, then it would drop it. In that case, you can either change your Publication Articles' properties and set the "Action when name is in use" to **TRUNCATE** instead of the default of **DROP** or create a Post-Snapshot script that re-creates the Trigger. Both are loosely discussed [here](https://blog.softartisans.com/2010/01/12/modifying-the-action-if-name-is-in-use-field-for-a-merge-replication-article/). I've used both options before.

Comment: I've discovered problems with this setup. It seems the triggers are not applied when a subscriber is reinitialised. I have opened a seperate question on it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301048/calling-triggers-on-replicated-table-when-reinitalising-from-snapshot)